# Beamer: error ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: beamer, errors

Having problems with LaTeX. The PDF file isn't being created and I have looked numerous times online. I think the problems lies in the user packages.

Here is the end the log code:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 154.

<use riskcenter2.jpg> [12])
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> Copulas.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> Copulas.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Copulas.log.
```

---

and here is the beginning of the document the user packages;

```
\documentclass[notes=show, Spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.emf}{bmp}{}{}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .gif} 

\usepackage[Spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.9,0.05,0.05}
%\usepackage{subfig}
```

---

If you need me to send the files I can do so.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you please post a full example, complete with begin document and end document, and also, smallest such document that produces this error (so, start from the beginning, put line by line and stop when this is the error or any equivalent algorithms...)

Comment: There seeems to be a problem with `bb` as an option.  Perhaps you had something like `\begin{figure}[bb]`?

Comment: Please add the offending frame code too. Otherwise we can't see the problem just by looking at the error message.

Comment: The beamer class plays a lot of dirty tricks with expansion to do what it needs to do.  This error is often the result of a mismatch in `\begin...\end`.  We can't tell for sure without looking at the offending part of the code, but do you forget an `\end{frame}`?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I have uploaded the file files below

Answer (score 2):

in your document you have a `\includegraphics[bb=...]{...}` which makes no sense. You should use

```
\includegraphics[viewport=...,clip]{...}
```

if really needed!

Comment: As requested here is ALL THE CODE

Comment: Here is the code structure
http://www.2shared.com/document/n_nQpUAJ/Code_structure_file.html

here is the log file
http://www.2shared.com/document/-FITxNB1/Logfile_Latex.html

Comment: Are you not able to find the lines with the above mentioned `\includegraphics`? You have several of it.  Simply delete the `bb= ...`

Answer (score 2):

(More of a comment, but I lack the reputation)

You seem to be using some control sequences that do not exist. Use < and > instead, or `\textgreater` (`\textless` respectively). 
(The [Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)] is a good place to look if you don't know how to obtain certain symbols)

Also, `\[` and `\]` delimit math-mode - you should not use `$` `$` inside a statement bracketed by `\[` and `\]`.